# Use a boolean expression with ng-pluralize

Tags: angularjs

Using `ng-pluralize` with this template:

```
Your subscription <span ng-pluralize count="::vm.account.subscription.expirationDays" 
                             when="{ '-1': 'has expired!', 
                                     '0': 'expires today!', 
                                     'one': 'expires tomorrow.', 
                                     'other': 'expires in {} days.'}"></span>
```

Yields the following result:

```
Expiration Days     Label
-1                  Your subscription has expired!
0                   Your subscription expires today!
1                   Your subscription expires tomorrow!
X                   Your subscription expires in X days.
```

However, this breaks as soon as a subscription expires **2 days ago**.

Is it possible to define a boolean expression as a when clause so that

`vm.account.subscription.expirationDays < 0 === 'has expired!'`

Currently I'm having to handle *expired* labels in a different element which kind of defeats the purpose of using `ng-pluralize`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do with ng-pluralize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your scenario is, albeit perhaps a common one, too complex for `ngPluralize`. I also doubt it will change, because `ngPluralize` is based on "plural categories": 
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

The problem being that en-US, Angular's default locale, defines only the categories "one" and "other". Anything that doesn't fall into those categories is explicitly defined (or inferred by `$locale.pluralCat`).

The three best options for your scenario that immediately come to me are:

**1)** Simplest would be to have two objects:

`when="count >=0 ? positivePlurals : negativePlurals"`

where, of course `$scope.count = vm.account.subscription.expirationDays`, `positivePlurals` is your positive phrases and `negativePlurals` is your negative phrases.

**2)** Wrap a localization library that supports many-or-custom plural rules (such as [i18next](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html)) in a directive, and use that instead. I'm not very familiar with the popular [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/), but at first glance it doesn't seem to support custom pluralization rules. It does, however, allow logic in interpolation, so you might get away with that.

**3)** Write a directive similar to `ngPluralize` that supports ("-other", "x", "other"). The source for `ngPluralize` is available [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngPluralize.js#L178). It would probably be as simple as modifying the statement at [L211](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngPluralize.js#L211) in a way similar to:

```
var countIsNaN = isNaN(count);
var countIsNegative = count < 0;

if (!countIsNaN && !(count in whens)) {
  // If an explicit number rule such as 1, 2, 3... is defined, just use it.
  // Otherwise, check it against pluralization rules in $locale service.
  count = $locale.pluralCat(count - offset);
  if(countIsNegative){
    count = '-'+count; // "-one", "-other"
  }
}
```